# I am unable to add a favicon to my webpage no matter how I try

Tags: html

I am working on a web page (i am not that good) and am trying to add a favicon to the web page however, no matter how I try I cannot add the image. I usually use this web page called faivcon.cc however even downloading the image it wouldn't work. Here is my code if it helps and the favicon I want to add bellow it:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=11AllWRhfRbN81DLR_dn6qmyKonqx4awI

https://www.favicon.cc/?action=icon&file_id=918895#

Comment: show the code you are using - not external links please :)

Comment: just looked at your linked drive.google url - you don't include your favicon in the head anywhere?

Comment: I am so sorry I will show the code next time, and yes I hadn't added any favicon in hopes that those who knew where I went wrong would add it. Basically, I added the <link> from favicon.cc right bellow my title.

Answer (score 0):

Load the favicon file to the root and just add code below to the head of your html doc

Comment: Hi! I also tried doing that, my best guess is that I copied my path wrong...at the place where I was supposed to add the path to my icon what I did was to right click and find properties of my favicon and copy paste the path. If you could give an example of how it works that would be awesome =)

Comment: Upload the icon to the root folder and paste this code to the head<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

Comment: Ok so 5 days of troubleshooting later and with jungle17's help I figured the problem, not only is the image supposed to be in the root folder but you cannot have a single <div> in your head or else the favicon's won't work. Thank you everybody =)

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons this wasn't working, the favicon wasn't in the root folder and there was a  in the header which causes favicons to not load.